# protobuf decode error using python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

When I try to decode a steam into a protobuf using python, I got this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1

My codes just read data from a file, and use "ParseFromString" to decode it.

```
f = open('ds.resp', 'rb')
eof = False
    data = f.read(1024*1024)
    eof = not data
    if not eof:
        entity = dataRes_pb2.dataRes()
        entity.ParseFromString(data)
        print entity
```

The data in the file is downloaded and saved from a http request. It seems that the data is not utf-8 encoded. So I use chardet.detect() and found that it is a ISO-8859-2.

The problem is, it seems that ParseFromString() needs the data to be utf-8 encoded (I am not sure). If I convert the data from ISO-8859-2 to utf-8. Then I got another error:

> google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message

How to correctly decode the data? Anybody have some advice?

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback?

Comment: How was the data saved from the http request and what did the http header say the encoding was? Did the save-http thing save it in utf-8?

Comment: _"Truncated message"_ how big is the message? If its more than `1024*1024` it is indeed truncated.

Comment: Protobuf data is not UTF-8 encoded. It is raw binary bytes, not text, so it doesn't have a charset at all. That said, the code you pasted does not show you trying to decode utf-8 so I'm not sure how the error arose. Please post the full error traceback, and also post the protobuf type as defined in your `.proto` file.

Comment: But the string fields are UTF-8 encoded when `pb_msg.SerializeToString` is performed